# Значение DataGridTextColumn в зависимости от выбора DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть DataGrid данные заполняются через биндинг:

```
<Custom:DataGrid Name="dgMenuProduct" ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
        <Custom:DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ColProduct" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Product}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                       SelectedValuePath="Prod" DisplayMemberPath="Prod" Header="Продукт" Width="4*"/>
        <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CenaProd}"  Header="Цена" Width="2*"/>
        <Custom:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Subvencia}" Header="Субвенция" Width="2*"/>
        <Custom:DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Path=KolvoProd}" Header="Количество" Width="2*"/>
        <Custom:DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ColTip" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=TipPP}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                                       SelectedValuePath="Tip" DisplayMemberPath="Tip" Header="Тип" Width="3*"/>
    </Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
</Custom:DataGrid>
```

Содержимое выпадающего списка берется из файла xml и загружается в класс:

```
public class ProductPit
{
    public ProductPit(string prod, double cena, string ediz)
    {
        Prod = prod;
        Cena = cena;
        EdIz = ediz;
    }

    public string Prod { get; set; }
    public double Cena { get; set; }
    public string EdIz { get; set; }
}
```

Сам Datagrid биндится из класса:

```
public class Menu
{
    public Menu(string product, double cenaprod, bool subvencia, double kolvoprod, string tippp)
    {
        Product = product;
        CenaProd = cenaprod;
        Subvencia = subvencia;
        KolvoProd = kolvoprod;
        TipPP = tippp;
    }
    // Наименование продукта - будет задаваться в DataGridComboBoxColumn, заполненного  List<ProductPit> months
    public string Product { get; set; }
    // Цена продукта - будет задаваться в DataGrid, в соответствии с выбранным продуктом питания
    public double CenaProd { get; set; }
    public bool Subvencia { get; set; }
    // Количество продукта питания - будет задаваться в DataGrid вручную
    public double KolvoProd { get; set; }
    public string TipPP { get; set; }
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы при выборе значения в выпадающем списке первого столбца, во второй столбец подставлялось соответствующее значение из класса ProductPit?

Comment: не очень понятно из описания, что вы хотите получить

Comment: у вас есть возможность добавить скриншот (а лучше гиф-ку) как это выглядит?

Comment: До конца не понятно, но судя по описанию достаточно обычной привязки...

Comment: @camtasia, мой ответ вам не подходит?

Comment: @Андрей, разбираюсь. мне не совсем понятно переопределение сеттера, Коллекцию ProductPits должна в классе Menu заполнится? и почему то ругается на FirstOrDefault.

Comment: @camtasia, подключите `using System.Linq;` `Содержимое выпадающего списка берется из файла xml и загружается в класс ...` - куда у вас загружается? В коллекцию какую-то?

Comment: @Андрей, using System.Linq; подключил ошибка на FirstOrDefault пропала, а что у Вас в коде - pp?

Comment: @camtasia, это просто параметр лямбда-выражения, у вас это будет так же, главное свою коллекцию, которая содержит все `ProductPit` подставьте

Comment: @Андрей, во время сборки проекта получаю ошибку на CenaProd = ProductPits // - это ваша коллекция, содержащая все ProductPit
            .FirstOrDefault(pp => pp.Prod == product)
            .Cena; может это быть из-за того что проект собирается под net3.5?

Comment: @camtasia какую ошибку?

Comment: @Андрей, пишет что ошибка в файле разметки MainWindow.xaml, но когда скрываю вышеуказанные строки, то сборка проходит нормально.

Comment: @camtasia, разобрались?

Comment: Всем спасибо, ответ Андрея помог, ему отдельное огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно переопределить сеттер `Product` в классе `Menu`:

```
string product;
public string Product
{
    get => product;
    set
    {
        product = value;
        CenaProd = ProductPits // - это ваша коллекция, содержащая все ProductPit
            .FirstOrDefault(pp => pp.Prod == product)
            .Cena;
    }
}
```

Хотя, я считаю, более правильным было бы хранить в классе `Menu` ссылку на конкретный `ProductPit`, а `Product` и `CenaProd` брать уже из него:

```
public ProductPit ProductPit { get; set; }
public string Product => ProductPit.Prod;
public double CenaProd => ProductPit.Cena;
```